# Add update cascade in exist primary key sql 2008

Tags: sql

I have a SQL 2008 DataBase. A table with compose PK. I need insert "update cascade"

Any idea ?

TKS

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE
        child
ADD CONSTRAINT
        fk_child_master
        FOREIGN KEY (col1, col2)
        REFERENCES master (col1, col2)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: I guess this assumes the OP doesn't already have a foreign key with an `ON DELETE` referential action and simply wants to add an `ON UPDATE` referential action to it. This is a fairly common scenario: "We can leave it as `ON UPDATE NO ACTION` because the key values will never change" and the assumption turns out to have been a fallacy :)